# Do PDO transactions cover PDO::query()?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

The PDO transaction examples at [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) show that `PDO::exec()` is transactioned, but there are no such examples using `PDO::query()`.

Do transactions cover `PDO::query()`?

Also, as I understand, `PDO::query()` returns a result set.  If transactioned, how can there be a result set, since the statement shouldn't execute until committed?  (Does this imply that `PDO::query()` is indeed *not* transactioned?)  I can't seem to find an official reference saying whether it is or it isn't.

Comment: Actually, I think I am misunderstanding transactions.  ``PDO::exec()`` also returns something: the number of affected rows; which implies that it is executed.  Then it must be that statements _are_ executed before ``PDO::commit()`` is called; but they are simply ``rollBack``-able.  So now it seems to me that ``PDO::query()`` _should_ be transactioned.

Comment: [*The result of any work done after this point will remain **invisible to other database-users** until the system processes a COMMIT statement. *](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction#In_SQL). The statements are indeed executed when you call them, it's the DB engine's responsibility to keep them inside the transaction.

Comment: @DCoder - Thanks for the reference!  After reading ckruse's answer, assuming he/she is correct, I want to clarify one thing.  The "work done [...] will remain invisible to other database-users" but indeed the work, from your own perspective, _will be done immediately_ (prior to committing) and _return results_ (whether in the form of result arrays, counts of rows affected, or success/failure indicators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missunderstand transactions. Transactions simply guarantee that the operations are atomic: either all operations succeed or none of them succeeds. Once you start a transaction every query will be executed and it will be logged in the transaction log. If an operation fails and you roll back, every operation will be reverted.

That said: if a query is transactionable does not depend on if you are using `exec` or `query` but it depends on the query type. `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are transactionable, other operations (such as `ALTER TABLE`) may or may not be transactionable, depending on your DBMS.

Comment: Gotcha.  So each operation is indeed "performed on call," but as a group, repealable and invisible to others until committed.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control) way, yes. You could also lock the relevant rows until commit of the transaction, e.g. MSSQL Server 2000 does this.